# HTML5 canvas lineWidth is being ignored

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm writing text on a canvas and am attempting to add some sort of border around it which should size dynamically based on the text size.

My code is:

```
<script>
var mainText='this is a test';
var mainTextSize=40;
var mainTextDimensions=getTextDimensions(mainText,mainTextSize,'verdana');

var smallStampCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
smallStampCanvas.width=mainTextDimensions.width;
smallStampCanvas.height=totalHeight;
var smallStampContext=smallStampCanvas.getContext('2d');
smallStampContext.textBaseline='top';

smallStampContext.fillStyle = '#FF0000'; 
smallStampContext.strokeStyle = smallStampContext.fillStyle;

smallStampContext.font = "bold "+mainTextSize+"px verdana";
smallStampContext.fillText(
    mainText,
    0,
    0
);

smallStampContext.strokeRect(0,0,smallStampCanvas.width,smallStampCanvas.height);
smallStampContext.strokeRect(0,0,smallStampCanvas.width,mainTextDimensions.height);
smallStampContext.lineWidth=Math.ceil(mainTextSize/4);
smallStampContext.moveTo(0,mainTextDimensions.height); smallStampContext.lineTo(smallStampCanvas.width,mainTextDimensions.height);
</script>
```

All works fine except for the lineWidth. No matter what value is entered it doesn't seem to have any effect. (line is always 1px) When logging it an integer 10 is entered.

Anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: could you show the code that is supposed to draw the thicker line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
smallStampContext.beginPath();
smallStampContext.lineWidth=Math.ceil(mainTextSize/4);
smallStampContext.moveTo(0,mainTextDimensions.height); 
smallStampContext.lineTo(smallStampCanvas.width,mainTextDimensions.height);
smallStampContext.stroke();
```

`moveTo` and `lineTo` don't draw "lines". Only `stroke` actually creates the line.

Comment: Bingo! Exactly what I was getting at - there's no code that did line drawing after the line width was set. rep++

Comment: damn, I failed at something that simple. Working great now! thanks a lot! +1